# How to copy exact Table layout from MS word to Latex?

Tags: tables

I need to copy exact layout of the following table (14 by 6) from Word to Latex for my academic journal. The problem is I’ve nearly tried everything I know that either tabularx or graphicsx will be used. I’ve gone through their documentation, but still can’t get the formatting in the right way I want it.

[image: required layout of table]

I’ve tried many things e.g. `\begin{tabular*}…\end{tabular*}`, using `{|6*{X|}}` and get different results. The best I got is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}    
\begin{table}
    \centerline{%
    \begin{tabular}{|l|*5{X|} }
    
    \end{tabular}
    }
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Possibly if the table could not fit the table in portrait, it’ll also be good enough to put it in landscape mode. Is there any other package that can deal with the situation better? Or can just anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: you surely had a error here saying that X was not defined column type, dont ignore errors.  `! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not a particularly nice table but if you really need this specific format...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry} % more generous margins

\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand*{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{A table containing some stuff.}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{6}{X|}}
\hline
\textbf{Author} & \textbf{Year of Publication} & \textbf{Mainly focusing problem/area} & \textbf{Any specific layered architecture} & \textbf{Main points} & \textbf{Any observable fault} \\
\hline
foo & foo & foo & foo & foo & foo \\
\hline
Bla [22] & 2012 & Designed specifically for this or that thingy & foo & Some text & Possibly won't work \\
\hline
foo & foo & foo & foo & foo & foo \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks for the snapshot. I was on a desktop with an unsupported Chromium version and I couldn't add pictures.

Comment: Always you're welcome and don't worry. It is a real pleasure.

Comment: +1 for the big understatement at the beginning. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg `:-D` I spent more time on how to write a polite judgement than on the code itself...

Comment: @campa table is a bit chunky.  i'll admit. i just cant get hold of latex these days. thanks for the help.